# Upper and lower case Č won't show up properly in dompdf

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, dompdf

I've been struggling with this for some time now.

So I have a simple file called index.php encoded in UTF-8. The content of this file is:

```
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
  '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><style> body { font-family: verdana; } </style></head><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p><p>Č Š Ž č š ž €</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Basically I'm trying to show the letters Č Š Ž correctly in PDF. Š and Ž work fine but I can't seem to get Č to show up properly, instead I see ? in my PDF file. Any ideas?

Comment: try a different font, you can specify fonts in dompdf

Comment: I tried all the fonts that are available, I'm also 100% sure that Verdana supports Č.

Comment: @Erik see Fabien's response. Verdana does support the character, but if the font isn't loaded into dompdf it won't be able to use it. Without a supporting font you'll get the results you noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [guide to enable Unicode in DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode) may help you. If you are using the latest version (0.6beta or trunk), there is also a new font installer in `dompdf/www/fonts.php` via your web browser, at the bottom. Also, be sure to check `dompdf/www/setup.php`.

Comment: Also, with 0.6.0 beta 3 you can skip loading a font and try one of the DejaVu fonts instead (e.g. try DejaVu Sans).